# Is it possible store return value of one function as Global Variable?

Tags: python, testcomplete

I  Have function register a patient that will Return  Medical record Number , Need store this as Global Variable to so that use the same for Different Functions Eg: Create Vital Sign , Create Lab Order etc.

```
aqTestCase.Begin(" User able to Register a Unknown patient")
   Log.AppendFolder("Unknown Registeration Logs")
   ERPage=Aliases.MedBrowser.pageER
   ReusableFunctions.ClickonObject(ERPage.RegisterUnknownPatientIcon)
   ReusableFunctions.ClickonObject(ERPage.UnknownRegMaleLabel)
   ReusableFunctions.setTextValue(ERPage.txtAge, "20")
   ReusableFunctions.ClickonObject(ERPage.UnknownRegregistrBtn)
   ReusableFunctions.ClickonButton(ERPage.AssignBuutonclose)
   AppReusableFunctions.getToastMsgs(ERPage)
   labelER = Aliases.VidaPlusBrowser.pageER.FindElement("//span[.='ER']")
   ReusableFunctions.ClickonObject(labelER)
   mrn = ERPage.FindElement("//div[10]/div[5]/app-er-patient-grid-mrn/span").contentText
   aqUtils.Delay(2000)
   ReusableFunctions.ClickonObject(ERPage.ERArrvialTime)
   Log.Message(" Unknown Patient Registred MRN is : "  +mrn)
   return mrn
```

Comment: ERPage=Aliases.MedBrowser.pageER
  
   return mrn

Answer (score 0):

You can set the variable as a global variable and return it.

```
def foo():
    global X
    X = 1
    return X
```

In your case, creating a class may work better.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def bar(self):
        return self.x

f = Foo(1)
f.bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = "awesome"

def myfunc():
  global x
  x = "fantastic"


myfunc()

print("Python is " + x)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?